# Karate Rest API Testing : getting com.intuit.karate - no runnable scenarios found: class.feature, env: null

Tags: karate, web-api-testing

I have recently started using Karate to automate API. As of now i have been using Jmeter for creating the automation frameworks.

I am getting the subject mentioned error when executing. I have checked the path which it displays, and a .feature file with a working code is present. I think it is related to the config file. I know its a simple thing which i am not able to pin point, would be great if you could point me in the correct direction.

Since i have only one environment i have kept that same everywhere in the config file.
[enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are new, may I suggest you follow the quick-start example to get started.

Please refer to the docs here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#quickstart

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeGroupId=com.intuit.karate \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=karate-archetype \
-DarchetypeVersion=0.8.0 \
-DgroupId=com.mycompany \
-DartifactId=myproject
```

Then try to run the `UsersRunner.java` | `users.feature` without issues. Then you can build on that.

Comment: Accepted. I have corrected the structure and it works now.